# Maximal ideal in $K[x_1,...,x_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm having some difficulty with this homework problem:

If $A=K[x_1,...,x_n]$, $K$  a field and $a_1,a_2,...,a_n $ $\in K$. The ideal $m=<x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n>$ is maximal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the evaluation map $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to K$ which takes a polynomial $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ to the point in $K$ given by $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$.

Comment: does the trick lie here that $K[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]/ker\phi$ isomorphic to $K$ correct me if I am wrong @Jared

Comment: @learnmore: You got it!

Comment: @Jared You are totally correct. Thanks.